# problems with session variables ci

Tags: codeigniter, session, logging, session-variables, session-cookies

my problem is that changing controller, My session variables are reset, creates a new cookie.HELP!

**controller**

```
if ($autenticacion) {
        // creamos un array con las variables de sesión 'usuario_id' y 'login_ok'
        $sesion_data  = array(
            'usuario_id' => $usuario,
            'login_ok' => TRUE
        );
        // creamos la sesión con dichas variables
        $this->session->set_userdata($sesion_data);
        // y redirigimos al controlador principal

        $datos['titulo'] = "Asociacion de futbol San Ignacio";
        $datos['contenido_plantilla'] = "bienvenido";
        $this->load->view('plantilla/plantillaAdmin', $datos);
```

**config**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']= 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']= 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please check whether you set the session when you are in www sub directory and then moves out when changing to new controller.

Comment: sessions must be loaded in the default controller?

Comment: when I call a controller via a link buton a new session is created